# Have your default store attributes run parallel with a second store when you update in admin

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, multistore, admin-panel

I have a standard default store 0 and i have a new store with an id of 13. When description or long description is updated in the main store i want it to update in my storeId 13 too. Almost any attribute that gets updated in my main store I would like to run parallel with my store 13. The only attributes i do not want to be updated together is "status, quantity, visibility and price". Is this possible through admin or will i have custom code to write?

Comment: Actually by default the default values should be copied to all the Store Views from the Default Configuration, unless you have removed the "Use Default Value" checkbox next to an individual attribute.

Unless I'm understanding your question wrong?

Comment: Thank you for responding. That's what i was thinking, i guess the real question is... how would i mass unselect these 4 attributes on that store level so they are never affected. "status, quantity, visibility and price" @LouisBataillard

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. But some (all?) of the attributes you listed (e.g. Price) can not be set on the Store View level AFAIK, as they are set globally.